# client side re-rediction to a view returned by Controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

On the client side, if user click a button I want take user to another page. That pageis returned by a method in Controller (assuming controller is home and method is MyMethod). Wondering on the client side can I do something like following or are there any better ways of handling this?

```
location.href =  @Url.Action("MyMethod", "Home");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only missing the quotes :)

location.href = '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "Home")';

Answer (score 0):

I like to use jQuery button to style standard HREF anchor tags to look like buttons.  That way its just a simple link using your @Url.Action above.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

Otherwise, yes, what you have is valid provided you wrap it in quotes as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
   location.href = base_url+'home/MyMethod';
```